# Required taxonomy term fields for node publishing?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, workflows, nodes

I want to create content which has shared some aspects. I am doing this through a taxonomy reference. The taxonomy has certain fields that describe each piece of content (in my case used cars).

In my workflow, I only want the content published if the taxonomy term reference has all its fields filled out. How can I automate this workflow?

Comment: Hard to understand what it is you're asking. Please clarify the question. At the moment, it's muddled up between taxonomy and node types, they're just referred to as Type A and Type B. Please make those distinctions at least.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workflow requirement that can be handled by [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

1. Set your *user car* type set to unpublished by default.
2. Create a rule for the **event** *Before saving content of type User Car* (or whatever your node type is called)
3. Add a *Data value is empty* **condition**. On the **Data selector** you'll want something like *node:field-MYTERM_FIELD:0:field-MYREQUIRED_FIELD* (it depends on your field names). Make sure to check the **Negate** checkbox so that the rule is triggered when the taxonomy field IS NOT empty.
4. Add a *Publish Content* **action**.

Comment: Thank you, much more simple and maintable than the custom module I suspected it would take.

Comment: No problem. Rules is a powerhouse for enforcing workflow. I edited the question to get toward the core of your answer (and less about the concrete nature of what you're content is describing). Make sure to mark the question as answer to help out future users.